# How to get a notification when the plugin is installed?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm making a WordPress plugin to get a notification when the plugin is installed.

I'm using [`is_plugin_active`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active)
but I still do not understand...

Comment: Where do you want to show the notification? As admin notice?

Comment: Note, if your plugin is hosted on WordPress.org or just about any plugin marketplace, this practice is not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommand using is_plugin_active() because if you rename your plugin directory which is done sometimes for security needs you're screwed.

If I were you I'd look into plugin you want to detect and select a core class or a core function of the plugin and test it with `if(class_exists('name_of_the_class'))` or `if(function_exists('name_of_the_function'))`.

Hope this will help, that how I proceed.